# Errors on tomcat's logs

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

i have a jsp site hosted on tomcat 7.
Even if the site seems to work, i can see a lot of errors on tomcat's logs.
Actually from time to time the site stops working and i have to restart tomcat.

But i cant understand what i should  do to solve this problems.

I dont run the server, so i dont know if i made mistakes in my code or the problems depend on the company that runs the server.

```
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:11 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlValidation' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:11 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlNamespaceAware' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:11 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '5' did not find a matching property.
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-12418"]
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2164 ms
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /home/jeansedi/jvm/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/manager does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5055)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5235)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/manager] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 3, 2014 2:17:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
```

Comment: Can you show us you tomcat_home/webapp dir??

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028610/severe-error-starting-static-resources-in-catalina-log

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603759/severe-error-starting-static-resources-in-tomcat-server-console

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438374/eclipse-error-starting-static-resources-java-lang-illegalargumentexception

Comment: You can ignore them, because the error is about another war or file presents in the webapps dir  and which is not a valid war ( web service ) file.